# How can I find the largest subarray sum if all the elements are negative and I have set the maxSum to 0, which is used to compare other elements?

Tags: java, arrays, sub-array

Can someone help me with this. My code is working fine but consider a case of [-2,-1]. Since my maxSum is set to 0. My output is coming 0 instead of-1. How should I modify my code?

Sample i/o:

```
Input: nums = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
Output: 6
Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.
```

```
class Solution {
    public int maxSubArray(int[] nums) {
    int sum=0,maxSum=0, i=0;
    if(nums.length==1) return nums[0];
    for( i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++){``
      sum+=nums[i];
      for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
        sum+=nums[j];
        if(sum>maxSum){
          maxSum=sum;
        }
      }
     sum=0;
     }
    return (nums[i]>maxSum)?nums[i]:maxSum;
    }
    }
```

Whenever the sum<maxSum I'm not touching the maxSum but when all the elements are negative sum<maxSum will always be true and I'm getting returned 0, rather I should get the maximum negative number. I don't want to change my approach can I get it right by some slight modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this:

```
class Solution {
    public int maxSubArray(int[] nums) {
    int sum=0,maxSum=0, i=0,negativeMaxSum=Integer.MIN_VALUE; //change here
    if(nums.length==1) return nums[0];
    for( i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++){
      sum+=nums[i];
      negativeMaxSum = (nums[i]<0 && nums[i]>negativeMaxSum) ? nums[i]: negativeMaxSum; //change here
      negativeMaxSum = (nums[i]==0) ? 0: negativeMaxSum; //change here (if there exist a 0 in the array then we don't need to show the greatest negative integer)
      for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++){
        sum+=nums[j];
        if(sum>maxSum){
          maxSum=sum;
        }
      }
     sum=0;
     }
    maxSum= (maxSum == 0 && negativeMaxSum>Integer.MIN_VALUE) ? negativeMaxSum: maxSum; //change here
    return (nums[i]>maxSum)?nums[i]:maxSum;
    }
```

You can create a new variable negativeMaxSum and compare it with each element, eventually negativeMaxSum will always store the maximum negative element and we will check if our maxSum is 0 and negativeMaxSum > least value for an integer(it means that there exist a negative integer) and we also checked if there existed a zero and if it did then we assigned it to our negativeMaxSum.